# Does Daylightsaving time cause DateTime calculations to become negative

Tags: c#, datetime, dst

We are currently rewritting the core of our services, basically we have scheduled tasks that can run on intervals, dates, specific times etc etc etc.

Currently we're wondering if daylightsaving might cause trouble for us, basically we calculate the next possible runtime, based on what days the task should execute and between what times, and what interval. We do this by taking the current time, and adding days/minutes/hours to this DateTime.

We then take this new run time and subtract DateTime.Now from this DateTime, leaving us with the timespan untill the next run.

How ever, what if the current time is 01:50 on a daylightsavings day, we add 20 minutes, which is our set interval, and end up with a time of 02:10, how ever since this is daylightsavinds, it's actually 01:10.

When i subtract the current time (01:50) from the 01:10 (which is actually 02:10) does this return a negative value which i need to work around or does this never ever return a negative value because DateTime is just a long underneath holding the proper information?

Basically, the following code, is the check needed or not?

```
//Get interval between nextrun and right now!
double interval = (NextRun - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;

//Check if interval is ever less or equal to 0, should never happen but maybe with daylight saving time?
if(interval <= 0)
{
    //Set default value
    interval = IntervalInMilliseconds;
}
```

We believe that this check isn't needed but our googling so far hasn't given us a definative answer.

Comment: I realize I'm late for this, but why not rely on the OS to do this for you, like scheduling a service/cronjob to run at the intervals you needed? It seems it could've made your program simpler (i.e. no dealing with the date stuff, just assuming that whenever it was launched, it was time to run). Was there a reason this was not considered or wouldn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use DateTime.UtcNow instead of DateTime.Now EVERYWHERE

Comment: Wouldn't this cause problems? when we want tasks to run between 20:00 and 05:00? Since it when using UtcNow that would make the tasks not run for an hour that it should? Or how would this behave?

Comment: Actually, to be more exact, we changed the calculations to use Utc, how ever all the configuration is done in local times. These local times then get changed to Utc. This was we can still configure our schedules to run the right hours without getting stuck with daylightsaving issues.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can try it yourself as it will help you understand how it works.

Essentially, using your example above, if you have 20 minutes to a local time, it would be 2:10 and not 1:10 as the computation is done in local time. If you want to get 1:10, you need to convert local time to universal time, add 20 minutes and then convert back to local time.

If you want real elapsed time, then you have to convert time to universal time before computing time difference. Also, if you work in local time, you won't be able to differentiate ambiguous time when the clock goes back.

Comment: Here are some additionnal links:  

[Five Common Daylight Saving Time Antipatterns of .NET Developers] (http://codeofmatt.com/2015/03/06/common-daylight-saving-time-mistakes-for-net-developers/)

Comment: If you want to support arbitrary time zone, then I think you need `DateTimeOffset`to properly handle all cases. Otherwise, with `DateTime`, it is possible to properly handle time in most case although it would be problematic to specify an ambiguous time (it would essentially be handled as being standard time). For that to works, you need to use `DateTime` member conversion to local time... **Thus I cannot recommend that approach unless are sure that you need to handle only current time zone and you already have a lot of code where time is stored in UTC time but displayed as local time.**